# Submit form using greasemonkey [JS]

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am writing a script to auto submit a form using greasemonkey. Here's my code:

`setInterval(function () {location.href = javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'DERIVED_REGFRM1_LINK_ADD_ENRL$118$');";}, 500);`

setInterval() is working fine as I tested it with an alert(). There must be a problem with how I am trying to call submitAction_win0().  Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use 'location.href' at all.
Here how to do it:

```
$("#form_id").submit(); //jQuery
document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); //plain JavaScript
```

and all together

```
setInterval(function () {
 document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
}, 500);
```